# Receive information about hot corner configuration on a Mac?

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults, sandbox

**Background:**
I'm currently working on an application that could interfere with OSX's hot corner feature. I want to analyse the current hot corner configuration programmatically so that I can implement the appropriate counter measures.

---

**What I've tried:**
I knew that I could fiddle with hot corners as root from within the terminal in the following way:

```
# Hot corners
# Possible values:
#  0: no-op
#  2: Mission Control
#  3: Show application windows
#  4: Desktop
#  5: Start screen saver
#  6: Disable screen saver
#  7: Dashboard
# 10: Put display to sleep
# 11: Launchpad
# 12: Notification Center
# Top left screen corner → Mission Control
defaults write com.apple.dock wvous-tl-corner -int 2
defaults write com.apple.dock wvous-tl-modifier -int 0
# Top right screen corner → Desktop
defaults write com.apple.dock wvous-tr-corner -int 4
defaults write com.apple.dock wvous-tr-modifier -int 0
# Bottom left screen corner → Start screen saver
defaults write com.apple.dock wvous-bl-corner -int 5
defaults write com.apple.dock wvous-bl-modifier -int 0
```

---

Since I did not find an official API I tried to access (read) the data this way:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *dict = [defaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.dock"];
```

This always returns `nil` however. I expected that I would not be able to edit them because of sandboxing. I didn't expect that I could not even read these defaults...

What would you suggest? Did I overlook something?

Comment: Did you try using CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(CFSTR("wvous-bl-corner"), CFSTR("com.apple.dock")? In my experience the CoreFoundation somehow gives you more access than the NSUserDefaults.